# Tracking objects from camera; PID controlling; Parrot AR Drone 2

Tags: opencv, camera, robotics, ar.drone

I am working on a project where I should implement object tracking technique using the camera of Parrot AR Drone 2.0. So the main idea is, a drone should be able to identify a specified colour and then follow it by keeping some distance.

I am using the [opencv](https://github.com/puku0x/cvdrone) API to establish communication with the drone. This API provides function:

```
ARDrone::move3D(double vx, double vy, double vz, double vr)
```

which moves the AR.Drone in 3D space and where

- vx: X velocity [m/s]
- vy: Y velocity [m/s]
- vz: Z velocity [m/s]
- vr: Rotational speed [rad/s]

I have written an application which does simple image processing on the images obtained from the camera of the drone using OpenCV and finds needed contours of the object to be tracked. See the example below:
[image]

Now ***the part I am struggling*** is finding the technique using which I should find the ***velocities*** to be sent to the ***move3D*** function. I have read that common way of doing controlling is by using ***PID*** controlling. However, I have read about that and could not get how it could be related to this problem.

To summarise, my question is how to move a robot towards an object detected in its camera? How to find coordinates of certain objects from the camera?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:**
So, I just realized you are using a drone and your cordinate system WRT the drone is likely x forward into image, y left of image (image columns), z up vertically(image rows). My answer has coordinates WRT the camera x = columns, y = rows, z = depth (into image) Keep that n mind when you read my outline. Also everything I wrote is psuedo-code, it won't run without many modifications

**Original Post**:
A PID controller is a Proportional–integral–derivative controller. It decides an action sequenced based on the your specific error.

For your problem lets assume the optimal tracking means the rectangle is in the center of the image, and it takes up ~30% of the pixel space. This means that you move your camera/bot until these conditions are met. We will call these goal parameters

[image]

```
x_ideal = image_width / 2
y_ideal = image_height / 2
area_ideal = image_width * image_height * 0.3
```

Now lets say your bounding box is characterized by 4 parameters

```
(x_bounding, y_bounding, width_bounding_box, height_bounding_box)
```

Your error would be something along the lines of:

```
x_err = x_bounding - x_ideal;
y_err = y_bounding - y_ideal;
z_err = area_ideal - (width_bounding_box * height_bounding_box)
```

Notice I have tied the z distance (depth) to the size of the object. This assumes that the object being tracked is rigid and doesn't change size. Any change in size is due to the objects distance to the camera (a bigger bounding box means object is close, a small one means object is far). This is a bit of an estimation, but without having any parameters on the camera or the object itself we can only make these general statements.

We need to keep the sign in mind when creating our control sequences, this is why the order matters when doing subtraction. Lets think about this logically. `x_err` determines how far off the bounding box is horizontally from the desired position. In our case this should be positive, meaning the bot should move to the left so the object moves closer to the center of the image. The box is too small, meaning the object is too far away, etc.

> z_err < 0 : means bot is too close and needs to slow down, Vz should be reduced
>      z_err = 0 : keep the speed command the same, no change
>      z_err > 0 : we need to get closer, Vz should increase
>
> x_err < 0 : means bot is to the right and needs to turn left(decreasing x), Vx should be reduced
>      x_err = 0 : keep the speed in X the same, no change to Vx
>      x_err > 0 : means bot is to the left and needs to turn right(increasing x), Vx should be increased

We can do the same for each y axis. Now we use this error to create a command sequence for the bot.

That description sounds a lot like a PID controller. Observe a state, figure out an error, create a control sequence to reduce the error, then repeat the process over and over. In your case the velocity would be the actions output by your algorithm. You will essentially have 3 PIDs running

> 1. PID for X
> 2. PID for Y
> 3. PID for Z

Because these are orthogonal by nature, we can say each system is independent (and ideally it is), moving in the x direction shouldn't affect the Y direction. This example also completely ignores the bearing information (`Vr`), but it's meant to be a thought exercise, not a complete solution

The exact velocity of the corrections is determined by your PID coefficients and this is where things get a little tricky. [Here](http://www.csimn.com/CSI_pages/PIDforDummies.html) is a easy to read (almost no math) overview or PID control. You will have to play with your system (aka "Tune" your parameters) through a bit of experimentation. This is made even more difficult because the camera is not a full 3d sensor, so we can't extract true measurements from the environment. It hard to convert an error of `~30 pixels` into `m/s` without knowing more information about your sensor/environment, But I hope this gave you a general idea of how to proceed

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it clearly does answer my question in full range of questions. And your assumptions about the coordinate system of the drone is correct. I did not quite understand "bearing information" that you stated. Do you mean by that side factors that could affect its motion, wind etc or smt else?

Comment: By "bearing information" I meant the angle. In the AR drone function it is the angular velocity. As far as I can tell that's the angle of travel from the x-axis of the drone (in the xy plane, i hope that made sense). You can probably use that angle along with horizontal movements to help track the target. But in my little example I only assumed you could slide on the y axis. not change the angular direction/bearing